# two Texts side-by-side without borders in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I was wondering if it is possible to have 2 Text widgets side by side
without any dividing line.

I thought that was what *borderwidth* was for, but, as you can see from this snippet, there is always a dividing line:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()       
cotext = Text(root, borderwidth=0)
chtext = Text(root,  borderwidth=0)
chtext.grid(column=0,row=0)
cotext.grid(column=1,row=0)
mainloop()
```

... or it is not possible?

EDIT: this is the last attempt, but still not working

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()       
cotext = Text(root, highlightthickness=0)
chtext = Text(root, highlightthickness=0)
chtext.grid(column=0,row=0,ipadx=0,padx=0,sticky=E+W+S+N)
cotext.grid(column=1,row=0,ipadx=0,padx=0,sticky=E+W+S+N)
mainloop()
```

EDIT now it's ok!

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()       
cotext = Text(root, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
chtext = Text(root, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
chtext.grid(column=0,row=0)  #,ipadx=0,padx=0,sticky=E+W)
cotext.grid(column=1,row=0)  #,ipadx=0,padx=0,sticky=E+W)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've set `borderwidth` to zero, the dividing line is probably the `highlightthickness` -- the thing that tells users which widget has the keyboard focus. Set it to zero for each widget (along with keeping the `borderwidth` at zero) and the dividing line will disappear. The other option is to leave it at 1, but set the `highlightbackground` attribute to the same color as the widget background.

Comment: nope, neither did work. highlightthickness at 0 shows a thinner but still visible dividing line; set it at 1 with highlightbackground as that of bg and it is still visible again. Could it be my desktop? (linux fedora13 with KDE)

Comment: @alessandro: I suppose it could be your desktop. Are you *certain* the *exact* code you posted, with setting `highlightthickness` to zero in both widgets still shows a space between the two widgets? You might also want to set the `sticky` option of the grid, the weight of the columns, and you might also want to explicitly set the `ipadx` and `padx` options in the grid command to zero. Any or all of those could contribute to extra spacing between widgets.

Comment: Works for me. @alessandro, you have to use _both_ `highlightthickness=0` _and_ `borderwidth=0`.